# Redmine revision keywords not working after migration

Tags: migration, redmine, revision

A couple of days ago we did a long due migration from Redmine 0.9.3 to 2.2.0. Everything migrated perfectly and seemed to work right away.

But we just found one function that no longer works. Redmine no longer seems to listen to the repository keyword. They are still found under Administration -> Repositories and it's still possible to browse the repositorie and see the changes. But Redmine will no longer associate revisions to redmine ids.

I already tried to remove the keywords, save the changes and readd them. No succes.
I told Redmine to re-read all the changesets using the command "rails runner "Repository.fetch_changesets" -e production"

But nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have You changed subversion system or commits  numbering?

`Link to a changeset with a *non-numeric* hash: commit:c6f4d0fd (displays c6f4d0fd).`

Or, this can be bug in Redmine
http://www.redmine.org/issues/13000

Comment: No svn has not been touched and neither is the numbering. 

We have the following keywords: REDMINEID for the normal linking and REDMINEFIX for fixes. This is not changed either.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the reference keywords they only work for new committs. If you want them work for old commits you have to delete the repository inside yor redmineproject and readd ir there. On the next fetch of changesets (if you have fetch changesets automatically activated yust openthe repository tab in your project) the keywords are used for all commits, including old onea.

For example you have a commit with "#1234" as commitmessage and the default keywords (ref, reference issue [as far as I remember]) rhe ticked 1234 would not be connected to the commit. Now changing the keywords to just * (single star means every issuenumber is bind without keyword) it would still be not connected. When now delete, readd and refetch changesets the issue 1234 would be connected to the commit